# Update parent component state using async requests in child component

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, react-apollo

I'm using React hooks + [Apollo hooks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/) to lazy load a series of components. These components make a query each time they are mounted. I want the parent component for these components to keep track of when each async call resolves with data.

I have a working example which passes the parent state to it's children and it gets updated in a callback. However, I have seen instances where the children are trying to update the parent state before the parent has time to update. This leads to the state being either updated more than it should, or not enough.

Here's an example of what I am currently doing:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const handleChange = () => {
    setState(state + 1); 
  }

  if (state < 10) {
    return <div>no more results</div>;
  }

  // it's possilbe that 5-6 mount at once and fire off queries
  return (
    <>
      {arr.map(c => <Child handleChange={handleChange} />)}
    </>
  )
}

const Child = ({ handleChange }) => {
  const [ loadMore, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        handleChange() 
      }
    }
  });

  // When a user scrolls into view, make request
  return (
    <Waypoint onEnter={loadMore}>
      {do something with data}
    </Waypoint>
  )
};
```

Is there a better way to manage the parent state when it's children are making async calls? Without introducing Redux?

Comment: You're doing good for me. The issue is that you have one parent state for n children. This will certainly fire a lot on scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (idx) => {
    setState(idx); 
  }

  if (state < arr.length) {
    return <div>no more results</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {arr.map((c, idx) => <Child handleChange={handleChange} key={idx} id={idx}/>)}
    </>
  )
}

const Child = ({ handleChange, id }) => {
  const [ loadMore, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        handleChange(id) 
      }
    }
  });

  // When a user scrolls into view, make request
  return (
    <Waypoint onEnter={loadMore}>
      {do something with data}
    </Waypoint>
  )
};
```